# Typescript with React: Using custom hook in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, axios, react-custom-hooks

I'm trying to use a hook inside of a useEffect call to run only once (and load some data).
I keep getting the error that I can't do that (even though I've done the exact same thing in another app, not sure why 1 works and the other doesn't), and I understand I may be breaking the Rules of Hooks... so, what do I do instead? My goal was to offload all the CRUD operation logic into a simple hook.
Here's MenuItem, the component trying to use the hook to get the data.

```
const MenuItem = () => {
  const [ID, setID] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState<Item[]>([]);
  const { getMenu, retrievedData } = useMenu();

  //gets menu items using menu-hook
  useEffect(() => {
    getMenu();
  }, []);

  //if menu is retrieved, setMenu to retrieved data
  useEffect(() => {
    if (retrievedData.length) setMenu(retrievedData);
  }, []);

  //onClick of menu item, displays menu item description
  const itemHandler = (item: Item) => {
    if (ID === null || ID !== item._id) {
      setID(item._id);
    } else {
      setID(null);
    }
  };
return ...
};
```

And here's getMenu, the custom hook that handles the logic and data retrieval.

```
const useMenu = () => {
  const backendURL: string = 'https://localhost:3001/api/menu';
  const [retrievedData, setRetrievedData] = useState<Item[]>([]);

  const getMenu = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(backendURL)
      .then((fetchedData) => {
        setRetrievedData(fetchedData.data.menu);
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setRetrievedData([]);
      });
  };

  return { getMenu, retrievedData };
};

export default useMenu;
```

And finally here's the error.

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

I'd like to add I'm also using Typescript which isn't complaining right now.

Comment: I don't see any invalid hook calls in the code provided; are you sure this is the component throwing the error? Calling `getMenu` inside a `useEffect` is allowed, you just can't call `useMenu` inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't even tell me where the problem is... but this is the only hook I have and the only time I'm calling it.

Comment: `it doesn't even tell me where the problem is... ` It doesn't come with a stack trace?

Comment: I quickly rebuilt the project without typescript and it works... so is this a typescript compilation error? I'm not even sure how I'd begin to get around it

Comment: This is not a typescript error.

Comment: I'm gonna be 100% honest with you, when you asked about the stack trace I ran the project again and it started working out of nowhere. I didn't change anything. I have 0 idea what happened or what I did. I know that is super unhelpful/anti-climactic but I genuinely have no clue. 
I really appreciate your help and if I ever run into the problem again I'll try to let you know what the problem was.

Comment: K. Only thing i can think of is that sometimes i've had cases where i change the code, but the hot-reloading doesn't work for whatever reason, so the browser is now running old code. So you might have been looking at an error that *used* to exist, but your editor showed code that no longer had the error. Then when you forced it to rebuild, you got on the latest code and your browser was now in sync with the editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things you can do to improve this code, which might help in future. You're right that you're breaking the rule of hooks, but there's no need to! If you move the `fetch` out of the hook (there's no need to redefine it on every render) then it's valid not to have it in the `deps` array because it's a constant.

I'd also make your `useMenu` hook take care of all the details of loading / returning the loaded value for you.

```
const fetchMenu = async () => {
  const backendURL: string = 'https://localhost:3001/api/menu';

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(backendURL);
    return data.menu;
  } catch (error: AxiosError) {
    console.log(error);
    return [];
  };
}

export const useMenu = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMenu.then(result => setItems(result);
  }, []);

  return items;
};
```

Now you can consume your hook:

```
const MenuItem = () => {
  const [ID, setID] = useState<number | null>(null);

  // Now this will automatically be an empty array while loading, and
  // the actual menu items once loaded.
  const menu = useMenu();

  // --- 8< ---
  
  return ...
};
```

A couple of other things -

- Try to avoid default exports, because [default exports are terrible](https://www.lloydatkinson.net/posts/2022/default-exports-in-javascript-modules-are-terrible/).
- There are a lot of packages you can use to make your life easier here! `react-query` is a good one to look at as it will manage all the lifecycle/state management around external data
- Alternatively, check out [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use), a collection of custom hooks that help deal with lots of common situations like this one. You could use the [useAsync](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useAsync.md) hook to simplify your `useMenu` hook above:

```
const backendURL: string = 'https://localhost:3001/api/menu';

const useMenu = () => useAsync(async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(backendURL);
  return data.menu;
});
```

And now to consume that hook:

```
const MenuItem = () => {
  const { value: menu, loading, error } = useMenu();

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingIndicator />;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <>The menu could not be loaded</>;
  }

  return ...
};
```

As well as being able to display a loading indicator while the hook is fetching, `useAsync` will not give you a memory leak warning if your component unmounts before the async function has finished loading (which the code above does not handle).

Answer (score 0):

After working on this project for some time I've also found another solution that is clean and I believe doesn't break the rule of hooks. This requires me to set up a custom http hook that uses a `sendRequest` function to handle app wide requests. Let me make this clear, THIS IS NOT A SIMPLE SOLUTION, I am indeed adding complexity, but I believe it helps since I'll be making multiple different kinds of requests in the app.
This is the sendRequest function. Note the useCallback hook to prevent unnecessary rerenders

```
const sendRequest = useCallback(
    async (url: string, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const httpAbortCtrl = new AbortController();
      activeHttpRequests.current.push(httpAbortCtrl);

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method,
          body,
          headers,
          signal: httpAbortCtrl.signal,
        });
        const responseData = await response.json();

        activeHttpRequests.current = activeHttpRequests.current.filter(
          (reqCtrl) => reqCtrl !== httpAbortCtrl
        );

        if (!response.ok) throw new Error(responseData.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
        return responseData;
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error);
        setIsLoading(false);
        throw error;
      }
    },
    []
  );
```

Here's the new useMenu hook, note I don't need to return getMenu as every time sendRequest is used in my app, getMenu will automatically be called.

```
export const useMenu = () => {
  const { sendRequest } = useHttpClient();
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState<MenuItem[]>([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMenu = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest(`${config.api}/menu`);
        setMenu(responseData.menu);
        setMessage(responseData.message);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    getMenu();
  }, [sendRequest]);

  return { menu, message };
};
```

Good luck